# How to change registrar?

Tags: domain-registrar

Currently I have a domain with godaddy as the registrar, and I have received many threats from them about losing it (for random reasons, like they always seem to do)

So I started looking for another hosting and registrar, but I don't know how to change my domain registrar without being at risk of someone else buying my domain.

Is there a secure way to do this?

Also, which registrar would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a secure way to do this.  The new registrar will provide you with complete instructions on how to do this.

Interestingly, I've never heard of godaddy threatening anyone with losing their domain registration.  I almost hate to ask why...

However, [register.com](http://www.register.com) and [networksolutions.com](http://networksolutions.com) are both good albeit a bit more expensive.

Comment: register.com? Have you ever tried a transfer out? Hardly recommended.

Comment: @RingØ: this was from 8 years ago....  things change.